# What hardware is used on the Basic Tier Cloud Machine Learning Engine?

Tags: google-cloud-ml

I am writing an academic article and need to document the hardware used to train my tensorflow models. I trained on the BASIC tier on google cloud machine learning engine. I cannot find documentation to the corresponding hardware specs. The price structure justs lists

[image]

But doesn't specify what those machine types are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GCE machine type for BASIC is n1-standard-4.

The GCE machine types are listed on the [training concept page](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/training-overview).
We are working machine transparency now. After which, Cloud ML machine types will be replaced by GCE machine types.